# regular expression multiple inner coincidences in a more wide context

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, multiple-instances

Im tring to find multiple coinciences in a phrase with regular expressions

Matching multiple dimensions in this phrase, results simple:
[working sample here](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=1270)

```
<?php
    preg_match_all("/(\d+\.\d)(x|cm)/", "120.0x140.0x215.0cm", $out);
    print_r($out);
?>

[0]=> array
    [0]=>120.0x
    [1]=>140.0x
    [2]=>215.0cm
[1]=> array
    [0]=>120.0
    [1]=>140.0
    [2]=>215.0
[2]=> array
    [0]=>x
    [1]=>x
    [2]=>cm
```

What I will use is the `$out[1]` array

The problem comes when I try to isolate this pattern from a context, it only match the last one value: [Working example here](http://lumadis.be/regex/test_regex.php?id=1271)

```
<?php
    preg_match_all("/<div>Dimensions: ((\d+\.\d)(x|cm))+<\/div>/", "<div>Dimensions: 120.0x140.0x215.0cm</div>", $out);
    print_r($out);
?>

[0]=> array
    [0]=><div>Dimensions: 120.0x140.0x215.0cm</div>
[1]=> array
    [0]=>215.0cm
[2]=> array
    [0]=>215.0
[3]=> array
    [0]=>cm
```

Im specting the `$out[2]` to contain multiple values, same as `$out[1]` in the first example

What im missing here? Is it possible to do it with regular expressions, I'll bet that might be possible.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when only one match is found, **but a capture group is found multiple times**, you only get the last one.

A possible solution would be to extract is from the `<div>` element, then using the first Regex you had.